# Try to append an integer to a list in a For Loop with If condition

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, append

I try to append integers that are over 10 (which is 13 in this case) to `MyList` with the following code, but an error occurred.

```
MyList = [2,2,2,7,13]
for i in MyList:
    if i >= 10:
        MyList.append(i)

print(MyList)

KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b61d86f65af6> in <module>
      2 for i in MyList:
      3     if i >= 10:
----> 4         MyList.append(i)
      5 
      6 MyList
```

If I use `append` as the following, it works. Can someone tell me the difference?

```
MyList = [2,2,2,7,13]
for i in range(len(MyList)):
    if MyList[i] >= 10:
        MyList.append(MyList[i])

print(MyList)
[2, 2, 2, 7, 13, 13]
```

Comment: your indentations are wrong at line 4 in both code, they both should give you error.

Answer (score 1):

The first example doesn't work because it gets stuck in an infinite loop. You keep appending to that list you're traversing. If you were to print it out at any point, it'd look like this `[2,2,2,7,13,13,13,13,13,13,13.....]`

In the second example, you're determining the size of the list at the very beginning (using the `len` function) and that doesn't get updated once you update the array because it was already computed.

Comment: If in the first example the list gets updated every time the "13" is appended and cause an infinite loop, why wouldn't the range(len(MyList)) in the second example be updated as range(6), range(7), range(8)...... when "13"is appended to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow,

In the upper code, you are constantly adding new values to the list, so that your for loop never finishes.

In the example below, you get the length of the list first and only loop len(MyList) times, not infinite.

Answer (score 0):

in following code you are adding the numbers in MyList and keep iterating over that only.

```
MyList = [2,2,2,7,13]
for i in MyList:
    if i >= 10:
        MyList.append(i)
print(MyList)
```

but in following you are iterating only the list size times. which have a limit.

```
MyList = [2,2,2,7,13]
for i in range(len(MyList)):
    if MyList[i] >= 10:
        MyList.append(MyList[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding items to `MyList` while iterating over it, causing an infinite loop in this case. A solution would be creating another list and merging the lists after the loop:

```py
MyList = [2,2,2,7,13]
toAdd = []
for i in MyList:
    if i >= 10:
        toAdd.append(i)

MyList += toAdd

print(MyList)
```